# Easy formula but stumping me anyway

Tags: calculated-column

Can anyone tell me where the error is in this formula??

```
=IF( [NA Score]>10
     ,"TCS or Comparable"
     , IF( [NA Score]>7
           ,"Discussion or Demonstration"
           , IF( AND [NA Score]<8
                 , [Change Level]=1
                 , "No Training Necessary"
                 , "Read & Acknowledge"
               )
          )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I reformatted your Formula with linebreaks..

In SharePoint `AND` is a function with parameters, just like the IF statement

see:
http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

So you need:

```
AND ( [NA Score]<8 , [Change Level]=1 )
```